# SQL Server 2012 Using CPU when Idle

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

My SQL Server 2012 is using 4-20% of my i7, but I don't have any application using SQL Server. This is Enterprise installed on a Win 7 box I use for development. I thought maybe it was just updating statistics or something but hours later it is still using the CPU for something.  Can someone please help me figure out what background processes might be running.  I don't have SQL Agent installed.  Just the engine, integration services, and the Management Studio.

Comment: I have SQL 2008 running on another PC and is uses 0.  This is what I expect.

Comment: If you reboot the server does the CPU remain at 4 - 20%?

Comment: What's using CPU in Task Manager?  Is it `sqlservr.exe`, `sqlwriter.exe`, or `sqlagent.exe`?  If so, open up SSMS and take a look at [SQL Server's Activity Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175518.aspx).

Comment: It is sqlservr.exe.  sqlagent isn't installed

Comment: It seems to be using less cpu now, but still don't understand why it isn't just sitting at 0.  There is only 1 table in 1 database and I am currently not using it. SQL Trace and SSMS are both closed

Comment: After reboot, it is at 0.  I don't know if it will start up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check sys.sysprocesses for any running processes.

Comment: It seems to have stopped whatever it was doing.  Thanks, I was looking for something like this to see what processes are running.  I will give an update if it happens again and this is useful.